# Use cloud as mirror to download R package

Tags: r, package, cloud, mirror

I'm using R version 2.15.1 on Mepis 12. 
I was trying to install a package called languageR (along with 3 more, see below), used in the book Analyzing Linguistic Data (R.H.Baayen). The problem is this:

```
> install.packages("languageR",repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/nalerive/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘languageR’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)
```

Upgrading is not really an option, unless it's **really** necessary to do so (I want to work with lme4 as well, which I already have, but have no experience with it in this R version yet).

So, I sent an email to the author and asked him what to do. His reply was:

> If you select the cloud as mirror, then you should be able to install
>   languageR, and separately e1071 (it lives on CRAN), the successor of
>   design (rms), and ape (it also lives on CRAN)

My question is, then, what is cloud mirror and where can I find it? 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I typed: `install.packages('languageR')` and then selected `0-Cloud` as a mirror instead of `Austria`, which I usually select, and the package installed.  `0-Cloud` was at the top of the list of mirrors.  Although, I am using the latest or second latest version of R.

Comment: If lme4 is your only reason not to update R, have a look at the [lme4.0 package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/lme4.0/?root=lme4), which provides the "old" lme4 for legacy code and then update R.

Comment: I cannot update to R 3.x.x because I have a problem with the package manager of my distribution: I cannot get it to access the newest distribution (something I'm working on with the Mepis community). I tried this on R <<install.packages("languageR", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")>> but got the same message.

Answer (score 1):

languageR has `R (≥ 3.0.2)` in its Depends (see [the CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/languageR/index.html)). Preferably you update R, but alternatively you can install from [an older source](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/languageR/).